# track employees browsing activity

Tags: ubuntu

I am working as IT admin. I want to keep track of all employees system activity, like which sites they are using etc. Basically, I want to checkout if anybody is doing outside or freelancing work in office hours. Is there any tool to check every users activity? Every employee uses Ubuntu system. As there are many tools for windows but didn't find any for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a proxy server. I myself have used [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as a proxy server and I consider it a reliable and stable solution.

Once you set up the server, you need to block all outgoing traffic to ports 80 and 443, except the address of the server. Then, you need to automate the configuration of the proxy server to the end user workstations - it won't be convenient I think to ask them to configure it by themselves.

And also need to consider a user friend front-end for the squid server, so that you could easily review browsing statistics (e.g. [lightsquid](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lightsquid/files/)).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @13nilux to some extent - however a lot of browsing is now done using https - so unless you are willing to compromise the chain of trust, a proxy server won't work.   (I also note that you can do transparent proxying and thus don't need to worry about automating configuration of the workstations).

If you are just trying to get a feel for what is happening, you could (instead, or in addition) require all DNS traffic (port 53) to be routed through your recursive nameservers and log the requests.  This will tell you what sites are being visited, but not what pages.  By tying the requesting IP addresses to the DNS queries you can build up a fair model of whats going on.

Another partial solution - which does not require monitoring - would be to look at their browser histories.   Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412844/can-i-view-firefox-history-with-the-terminal)  for more info, but basically its a matter of querying the .sqlite databases used by Mozilla.   The answer from Pawomoy (currently the last one) is, in effect, a cut and paste script which will list the URL's visited today.   If you maintain central authentication you should be able to use SSH to log onto each system and programmatically retrieve this data.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to rely on DNS information, because .. you can go to a website because a certain business process requires it. That website however, has links/ads/commercials with videos and pictures, which will generate more DNS traffic to resolve let's say youtube etc etc so that the user's browser can load the content.

Comment: Of-course DNS is not the best way of doing it, but it can be by far the cheapest, easiest and least intrusive - I fully acknowledge it will contain crap you don't need, and won't capture everything - but it gives a quick and dirty overview of the landscape for the cost of a tcpdump on the appropriate interface.